# .NET webservice app and IIS 7.5 problems

Tags: configuration, iis-7.5, web-services

I have installed a 7.5 IIS server and tried to install a webservice. But whatever i do i cannot get it to work. I just get 404 back and a blank page. Here is the log:

```
2013-03-14 08:17:41 ::1 GET /getservice/Login User=aaa&Password=aaa 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:19.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/19.0 404 0 2 46
```

I have a Web.config with a connection to a MSSQL server. Is that something wrong with my connection. Shouldn´t it work "out of the box" or do i need to install extra in order to connect to the db?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=db.web.org;initial catalog=ThisC;User ID=User22;Password=qwerty;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check

1. Set default page in IIS
2. Permission in web.config, if it is windows authentication, install this feature in IIS
3. Remote access to MSSQL server.

Comment: Thanx for answering. I did those things. Still turns up 404. Same log error as before. I really can´t understand why this is not working. The same file is working on another machine (IIS 7.5).

Comment: what error you are getting when you do browse from the IIS console?.can you post that error page. you will be getting the exact error when you browse from the IIS console.